# Take integer inputs till the user enters 0 and print the sum of all numbers (HINT: while loop) (coding language:- JAVA)

Tags: java

IN this problem we have to print the sum of all the numbers until the user enters zero.

my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class printsum_until_enter0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        //int count = 0;
        int x = in.nextInt();
        while (x >0) {
            if (x > 0) {

                sum = sum + x;
                System.out.println(sum);
                x--;

            } else {
                System.out.println("no data was entered");

            }

            x--;
        }

    }
}
```

it runs infinitly before writing X--...but now it takes only one input and after that it is executed...but it supposed to execute after entering 0 and sum of all the numbers before entering 0. But it is not happeing.Any solution guys...Code in java..

Comment: Hint: how many times is your code calling `nextInt`?   Look carefully!

Comment: *"Any solution guys"*  - Hint: you can solve this for yourself using the [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) technique.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you only ask the user for input once. What you want to do is move the scanner.nextInt part somehow into your loop. In java there is a concept called do while loop which executes the loop body first and then checks the loop condition if it should be repeated. If you do not want to use a do while loop you can use a while true loop to check if the input was 0 and exit. Notice also how x needs to be initialised before the function body to be recognized by the while statement

Unfortunately, I did not get why you decreased x in your code. Let me know if I misunderstood your question or you have any more questions

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int x = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Please insert a number: ");
            x = in.nextInt();

            // If x is 0 it wont change the sum
            sum += x;
            System.out.println(sum);

        } while (x > 0);

        System.out.println("no data was entered");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your code

```
   package test1;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class printsum_until_enter0 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int sum = 0;
            int x = in.nextInt();
            while (x >0) {
                if (x > 0) {
                    sum = sum + x;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("no data was entered");
                }
                x = in.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
do {
  x = in.nextInt();
  if(x > 0) {
    sum += x;
  }
} while(x > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0, a =1;
        while(a != 0){
            a = sc.nextInt();
            sum = sum + a;
        }
        System.out.print(sum - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.dev.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumofNintegers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Please enter the Numbers you want to add: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    
    
    while(a>=0) {
        
        if(a==0) {
            break;
        }
        
        else {
            sum = a + sum;
            
        }
        
        a = sc.nextInt();
        
    }
    
    System.out.println("The sum of given numbers is: "+sum);
    
    

}
```

}